# Graphing time as a function of another variable

Tags: orbital-motion, time, satellites

I'm sorry if this is not the correct place to post this, but it seems most applicable.

I'm graphing the time for a satellite to decay, which depends on the altitude it orbits at, making time a dependent variable. Graphing convention is that dependent variables go on the Y axis, however since time is almost always an independent variable I feel as if a graph with time on the X axis would be easier to understand. Which axis should I graph time as??

Comment: You may use whatever axis you feel better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of axes is, of course, a convention, and you are free to choose any labelling you like.

However, I think that in this case putting time on the $x$ axis would be confusing, as it would suggest your graph is showing the change of a satellite's altitude with time. In this case time is a dependent variable, and so it's perfectly fine to put it on the $y$ axis.